# Complementary DNA synthesis

Tags: reverse-transcription, cdna

Does the reverse transcriptase enzyme recognize thymine to synthesize the complementary strand of cDNA?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: One reason we do it as @theforestecologist suggests is that it avoids us repeating stuff at you that you already know or have already looked up.